# How to make ion-item allow overflow in Ionic 2?

Tags: css, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want to make `ion-item` allow overflow of it's contents. I tried the following css (scss to be specific)

```
ion-item{
   overflow: visible;
   height : 220px;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried adding `overflow : visible` property to the elements generated by `ion-item` (like `.item-inner`, `.item-block`), but that didn't work too.

## Edit (Adding code snippets)

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>
    <div class="rel-container">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <div>Name1</div>
          <div>Name2</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
          <div class="error-container">
            <div class="error">a quick brown fox</div>
          </div>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

home.scss

```
ion-item,ion-list,ion-label, .item-md, .item-block, .item, .item-inner, .input-wrapper, .rel-container, .button-effect{
    overflow: visible;
}

page-home {
    ion-item{
        height: 9rem;
    }


    .error-container{
        padding: 5px;
        background: red;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 400;
    }

    .rel-container{
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u put !important?

Comment: It should be `overflow: auto;` without `"` quotes

Comment: If you inspect the element with the browser's dev tools, what does it say about that property?

Comment: @LGSon I mean to say that `overflow: "visible";` should be without quotes like this `overflow: visible;`

Comment: In actual code, it is without quotes. Typo in question. Will correct that

Comment: And maybe use semi-colon `;` at the end of each property line... not comma

Comment: @LGSon The property is getting applied when I inspect element, but the overflow is not happening

Comment: @LGSon haha that was in hurry.. :)

Comment: @JyotiPathania Yes :)

Comment: @Lakshay the property is getting applied to the element when I inspect DOM, so  I don't think `!important ` will make any difference

Comment: I guess you have to provide a code snippet that actually reproduces the issue, as we ran out of guesses :)

Comment: @LGSon updated the description with code snippet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before I answer, here are some miscelleneous details

```
Ionic v3.3.0
Angular v4.1.2
```

The problem that `overflow` was not working as expected, was the CSS property `contain : content;` applied by Ionic for `.item`.

(More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain)

To solve this I just had to override it with

```
.item {
    contain:none;
}
```

Peace! ✌️✌️✌️

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the text-wrap directive:

```
<ion-item text-wrap>
Multiline text that should wrap when it is too long
to fit on one line in the item.
</ion-item>
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/